# Cannot convert json array to rows with PostgreSQL json_array_elements() function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to perform a join on a table with array values where each element in the array becomes a new row.

I'm working on a database extracting specific keys from very varying json format. Depending on my extraction query the initial data looks different. With

```
SELECT id, content->'data' FROM other_table
WHERE content->'data' IS NOT NULL;
```

I get:

```
-----------------------------
  id (int)   |  data (json)
-----------------------------
   1         | [abc, def]
   2         | [ghi, jkl]
   3         |  mno
```

And with

```
SELECT id, content->>'data' FROM other_table
WHERE content->>'data' IS NOT NULL;
```

I get:

```
-----------------------------
  id (int)   |  data (text)
-----------------------------
   1         | ["abc", "def"]
   2         | ["ghi", "jkl"]
   3         |  "mno"
```

and I would like to end up with:

```
----------------
  id   |  data
----------------
   1   |  abc
   1   |  def
   2   |  ghi
   2   |  jkl
```

However, with

```
SELECT id, json_array_elements(data) 
FROM (SELECT id, content->'data' as data FROM other_table
      WHERE content->'data' IS NOT NULL) s
```

I keep getting

```
ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar 
SQL state: 22023
```

I think the problem lies with the specific rows that are not 'mapped' into json arrays, but are just single elements.

How can I cast these single elements to arrays?

I looked at https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/the-lazy-analysts-guide-to-postgres-json and according to that this should be possible.

I'm using postgres 10.2.

Comment: Your query is ok, see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/14ea8/1). You may want to use `json_array_element_text()` to get strings without double quotes.

Comment: @klin I think that would work if my initial data would be formatted as valid JSON